# Kotlin RecyclerView in Fragment - Navigation architecture component - null error

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-components

I am trying to create a RecyclerView in a fragment but I am getting a null error on the RecyclerView. I was able to create the fragment successfully using the new Navigation architecture component with a bottom navigation bar. I am running Android Studio canary 3.2 Beta 1.

Note sure where I have gone wrong as I am not getting any red lines in Android Studio.

**Debug Error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.projects.arise.mytestapp, PID: 28285
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.arise.mytestapp/com.projects.arise.mytestapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: rview_keys must not be null
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: rview_keys must not be null
>           at com.projects.arise.mytestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:55)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

        val navController = host.navController
        setupBottomNavMenu(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
    }

    private fun setupBottomNavMenu(navController: NavController) {
        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.navigation)?.let { bottomNavView ->
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavView, navController)
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentKeys.kt**

```
class FragmentKeys : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keys_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        //val rview_keys: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rview_keys)
        rview_keys.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rview_keys.adapter = AdapterKeys(KeysListObjects.keys)
    }
}
```

I commented out the one line above because I was getting an "unresolved reference" error on "findViewById". This line didn't seem to be necessary as it was not in other people's code. For example: [Kotlin Android Fragment recyclerView and context issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427209/kotlin-android-fragment-recyclerview-and-context-issue)

**AdapterKeys.kt**

```
class AdapterKeys(val keys: List<KeysList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterKeys.KeysViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KeysViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_keys, parent, false)
        return KeysViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return keys.size
    } //override fun getItemCount() = keys.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KeysViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val keysList = keys[position]
        holder.setData(keysList, position)
    }

    inner class KeysViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun setData(keysList: KeysList?, position: Int) {
            itemView.tview_Keys.text = keysList!!.keysText
        }
    }
}
```

**ModelKeys.kt**

```
object KeysListObjects {
    val keys = listOf<KeysList>(
            KeysList("Testing1"),
            KeysList("Testing2"),
            KeysList("Testing3")
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do that in `onActivityCreated` and not in `onViewCreated`??

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I did that based on a previous SO question (linked in my original post). You are correct: in onViewCreated is where it should sit - see my post below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting the error because you commented this

> //val rview_keys: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rview_keys)

there is no declaration of **rview_keys** as a variable. So it is considering rview_keys as a view because in your activity you have a view with id **rview_keys**.

Following lines from error just confirm it.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: rview_keys must not be null at com.projects.arise.mytestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:55) at

Check code at line number 55 of MainActivity.

The reason these people don't have that line is that they are using it as a view.
And you can't use it as a view in onActivityCreated().

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked in the emulator when I used it as a view in onViewCreated instead. So the line I commented out was needed after all; which makes sense to me because I remember hearing/reading somewhere that findViewById boilerplate is no longer required in Kotlin.

Turns out I had other issues in Android Studio 3.2 that I needed to deal with also that prevented my test app from rebuilding successfully. Will detail this in a post below.

Comment: And the code at line 55 was for my bottom nav bar which incidentally is also the findViewById line in MainActivity.kt. Got my app to work again when I commented out all the related RecyclerView code. So not sure why it was throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do two things to get this to work:

1. Move the two rview_keys lines of code from onActivityCreated to onViewCreated (which I believe is earlier in the fragment lifecycle). Thanks to above posters for their feedback here! So now my fragment class looks like this:

**FragmentKeys.kt**

```
class FragmentKeys : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keys_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rview_keys.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rview_keys.adapter = AdapterKeys(KeysListObjects.keys)
    }
}
```

2. I was still getting build errors so I tried changing one of the Kotlin dependencies in my build.gradle file (jdk7) back to what it was before even (jre7) though I was getting a deprecation warning.

The new dependency I was being asked to use - which wasn't working:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

The old dependency I switched back to - which is working (for now):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```