# recyclerview in fragment context not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im creating a really basic `recyclerview` in `fragment_home.xml` which is linked to a `<FrameLayout />` inserted in `activity_main.xml`

It works well...until I create the `HomeFragment` class in `HomeFragment.kt`, which inflates `fragment_home.xml`

Then I want to add up the arrayList (`arrayHomeMenu`) in the function `onActivityCreated()`

my problem is with this line

```
  val homeMenuAdapter = HomeMenuAdapter(arrayHomeMenu, this) //context "this" appears with red underline
```

It retrieves error, so I cant continue...

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
   class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
   override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

 }


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)


    //create list of words
    val arrayHomeMenu = ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>()

    arrayHomeMenu.add(HomeMenuModel("Verbs","List of 461  words", R.drawable.ic_logo))
    arrayHomeMenu.add(HomeMenuModel("Nouns","List of 52 words", R.drawable.ic_logo))
    arrayHomeMenu.add(HomeMenuModel("Adjectives","List of 65 words", R.drawable.ic_logo))
    arrayHomeMenu.add(HomeMenuModel("Adverbs","List of 345 words", R.drawable.ic_logo))

    val homeMenuAdapter = HomeMenuAdapter(arrayHomeMenu, this) //context "this" appears with red underline


    homeMenu_recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    homeMenu_recyclerView.adapter = homeMenuAdapter

}
```

This is a `context` problem....

I tried to replace `this` by `activity`, `context`, `Context`, `applicationContext` with not success at all...

**HomeMenuAdapter.kt**

```
class HomeMenuAdapter(val arrayList: ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>, val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeMenuAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    ....//correct content
   }
```

It works correctly when I create the recyclerview direct in `activity_main.xml` and work directly with `MainActivity.kt`

Once I move the recyclerview to a fragment...it throws the error described above.

**HomeMenuModel.kt**

```
  class HomeMenuModel(val hm_title:String,val hm_description: String, val hm_image:Int)
```

I was checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427209/kotlin-android-fragment-recyclerview-and-context-issue), but no success...

**what am doing wrong??** thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can use `this` as context inside an Activity, is because [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) extends Context.

[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) however does not extend Context so you cannot use `this`.

The reason why `activity`, `context` also don't work is Kotlin's distinction of nullable types. While `activity` and `context` do return a Context, the return value is nullable. You can see this by paying close attention to the error message that appears when hovering over the red underline:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
Context? (or FragmentActivity?)
```

The question mark indicates that this is a nullable type, while a non-nullable Context is required. The reason why they're nullable is that the Fragment can only retrieve the Activity when it is attached to it, which is not always the case.

However, Fragment has a convenient method called [`requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext()) to work around this issue. It has a non-nullable return type but will instead throw an exception if it cannot retrieve the context, so it is on you to make sure to only call it when the Fragment is attached.

In short, you should be able to instantiate your adapter like this:

```
val homeMenuAdapter = HomeMenuAdapter(arrayHomeMenu, requireContext())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a Fragment this can't be passed as a context:

```
val homeMenuAdapter = HomeMenuAdapter(arrayHomeMenu, this)
```

In the above code you are trying to pass fragment as a context, so instead what you can do is get the context of the fragment. So you can do:

```
val homeMenuAdapter = HomeMenuAdapter(arrayHomeMenu, requireContext())
```

Comment: Fragments are usually part of some activity, and requiring/getting context will give you the parent's context which is usually the activity.